# Cannot load external ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to load an external XAML file using this code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/OfficeStyle;component/OfficeStyleWindow.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Opening reflector on the "OfficeStyle" DLL gives:

[alt text http://robbertdam.nl/share/p3.png](http://robbertdam.nl/share/p3.png)

Running the app gives this error:

[alt text http://robbertdam.nl/share/p4.png](http://robbertdam.nl/share/p4.png)

The error pops up and the XAML code I've placed at the beginning of this post. What am I missing? The XAML file I'm trying to load contains a bunch of Styles etc. I want to reuse in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the build action for your OfficeStyleWindow.xaml file ? It should be Page, not EmbeddedResource

Comment: Well, I started with "Resource", but than Reflector does not show the xaml file. It only shows when I make it EmbeddedResource. In both cases the resource file cannot be located.

Comment: Sorry, I realize I made a mistake... the build action should be Page, not Resource ; I updated my answer. You won't see the XAML file in Reflector because it will be compiled as BAML. In Reflector it will appear as a MemoryStream resource named "Resources/OfficeStyleWindow.baml", in the resource module OfficeStyle.g.resources

Comment: Thanks, making it "page" did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the folder name to the pack path.

pack://application:,,,/OfficeStyle;component/Resources/OfficeStyleWindow.xaml